# submiting python scripts using qsub

Tags: python

I've created a python script which generates a bunch of other scripts and submits them using qsub.

I've added permission to my files and subsequently tried to run them using os:

```
    st = os.stat(file_name)
    os.chmod(file_name, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)

    os.system("bash qsub -l nodes=1:ppn=1" + file_name)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error message:

```
/usr/bin/qsub: /usr/bin/qsub: cannot execute binary file
```

How can I circumnavigate this issue?

Comment: Could it be as simple as missing a space after `...:ppn=1"`?

Comment: This is a bad way. Don't they have available Python or REST APIs?

Comment: Usually daisychaining jons together like this is a bad way to use HPC. I would recommend rethinking your workflow. It totally depends on the cluster management software being used, which you haven't mentioned. In Univa this is super easy to achieve https://blogs.univa.com/2016/05/univa-short-jobs-video-5-the-submission-api/

Comment: Why not just `os.system(qsub ...)` (i.e. drop the bash call)?

Comment: @duhaime  You're right! It works! Thank you!

Comment: Amen. I'll add an answer you can accept if you like. Have fun with qsub!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `bash` before running `qsub`, you can just run the `qsub` command itself:

```
import os
file_name = 'hello.py'
os.system("qsub -l nodes=1:ppn=1" + file_name)
```